# Update Database with JDBC having some values which should be ignored

Tags: java, database, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I am having some troubles using JDBC for updating a table-column. If I have a table e.g `User(name,address,hobby,...)` imagine about 15 fields. Then I get via frontend an Object from a form, where a user can type in all entries which should be changed. Now I need to save the changes in the database, but not all of the fields got changed, so my DAO has some `null` values. For example `name` and `address` should be changed, the other entries in the table shouldn't. Is there any smart way to put that into a JDBC `PreparedStatement`? Or do you know other solutions? I am trying to avoid a lot of `value != null` statements.

Thanks in advance!

(I am using spring as my backend, and angular in frontend)

Comment: Without any code it is hard to help you. Off the top of my head, you should first retrieve the actual values from the database, and let the user modify those values. Then you won't have any nulls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Spring, you can use the `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`, but the real trick is the use of `COALESCE` to use a fall-back value when the value given is `NULL`:

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

public void updateUser(int id, String name, String address, String hobby) {
    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    String sql = "UPDATE User" +
                   " SET Name = COALESCE(:name, Name)" +
                      ", Address = COALESCE(:address, Address)" +
                      ", Hobby = COALESCE(:hobby, Hobby)" +
                 " WHERE Id = :id";
    MapSqlParameterSource paramMap = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    paramMap.addValue("id"     , id     , Types.INTEGER);
    paramMap.addValue("name"   , name   , Types.VARCHAR);
    paramMap.addValue("address", address, Types.VARCHAR);
    paramMap.addValue("hobby"  , hobby  , Types.VARCHAR);
    if (jdbcTemplate.update(sql, paramMap) == 0)
        throw new EmptyResultDataAccessException("User not found: " + id, 1);
}
```

Or, if you use a POJO with the user data:

```
public class User {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String hobby;

    // Getters and setters here
}
```

```
public void updateUser(User user) {
    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    String sql = "UPDATE User" +
                   " SET Name = COALESCE(:name, Name)" +
                      ", Address = COALESCE(:address, Address)" +
                      ", Hobby = COALESCE(:hobby, Hobby)" +
                 " WHERE Id = :id";
    BeanPropertySqlParameterSource paramMap = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(user);
    if (jdbcTemplate.update(sql, paramMap) == 0)
        throw new EmptyResultDataAccessException("User not found: " + id, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution you can have is using SimpleJdbcInsert and adding usingGeneratedKeyColumns("ID").

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;
    
@Override
    public ResponseEntity<Void> insertEntity(Entity obj) {
        SimpleJdbcInsert simpleJdbcInsert = new SimpleJdbcInsert(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource());
        simpleJdbcInsert.withTableName(TABLE_APP_REPO).usingGeneratedKeyColumns("ID");
        BeanPropertySqlParameterSource paramSource = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(obj);

        try {
            simpleJdbcInsert.execute(paramSource);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
```